# Error: default parameter specifiers are not permitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

In the first second line string `SqlOutputParameterName = "MSG"` --near = I'm getting this error. I'm using 3.5 frameworks. How to resolve this

```
 public static DataTable JobsGetAll()
 {
      //SqlParameter[] CmdParamColl = new SqlParameter[1];
      string StoredProcedure = "GetJobsAll";
      //DataConnectSql.DataConnectParametersAdd(ref CmdParamColl, "@WebName", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, ApplicationName, 0, 500);
      return DataConnectSql.DataConnectResultDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, StoredProcedure);
 } 

 public static DataTable DataConnectResultDataTable(CommandType CmdType, string CmdText)
 {
    SqlCommand CmdExec = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable DtResult = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        CmdExec.Connection = DataConnectionOpen();
        CmdExec.CommandType = CmdType;
        CmdExec.CommandText = CmdText;
        SqlDataAdapter DapResult = new SqlDataAdapter(CmdExec);
        DapResult.Fill(DtResult);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        DtResult = null;
        //throw;
    }
    finally { CmdExec.Connection.Close(); }

    return DtResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the output parameter before executing the query.
Add the following line you your code, before the `try` block:

```
CmdExec.Parameters.Add("@" + SqlOutputParameterName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

in context:

```
public static string DataConnectExecuteNonQuery(CommandType CmdType, string CmdText, string SqlOutputParameterName = "Msg")
{
    SqlCommand CmdExec = new SqlCommand();
    CmdExec.Connection = DataConnectionOpen();
    CmdExec.CommandType = CmdType;
    CmdExec.CommandText = CmdText;
    CmdExec.Parameters.Add("@" + SqlOutputParameterName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; //** HERE **//
    string msg;
    try
    {
         CmdExec.ExecuteNonQuery();
         msg = CmdExec.Parameters["@" + SqlOutputParameterName].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: im getting same error . because im working in 3.5 version.@zohar

Comment: You've changed the code, my answer is no longer relevant.